# Vim got unexpectedly slow

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

After a couple of months using vim as my default editor and growing my `.vimrc`, my vim started to slow down to a point where it even freezes sometimes. I've already tried to run vim without any personal config and it runs like a breeze. I have also tried to run:

```
:profile start profile.log
:profile func *
:profile file *
" Do things that could cause a slow down
:profile pause
:noautocmd qall!
```

According to the log, it seemed **vim-polyglot** and **YouCompleteMe (YCM)** plugins were causing the slowness. Yet, even after removing those plugins from my `.vimrc` vim was still very sluggish, especially when pasting content from the clipboard or working with big files simultaneously.
As a side note I'm working mainly with PHP, Python, JS and HTML.

Comment: How are you pasting contents from your clipboard? I advise against using `ctrl-(shift-)v`/`cmd-v`, as vim has to interpret the content as if they were typed (including abbreviations, insert mode mappings, autoindent, etc.). Vim has a paste mode `:set paste` that disables these features temporarily (until `:set nopaste`), alternatively, if you have the `+clipboard` feature, you can paste in normal mode with e.g. `"+p`.

Comment: Could you show us your vimrc?

Comment: @romainl here it is https://gist.github.com/Charliiee/911b7dda9254c5dd2e179d2e222fd144

Comment: I suspect moving all your stray autocommands into properly reset augroups is going to help you a lot. See https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/wiki/vimrctips#wiki_wrap_your_autocmds_in_proper_augroups